# Missing tools.jar in SpringTools Suite when invoking via command line

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, tools.jar

I'm seeing the following screen:

[image: similar question]

upon STS startup via script:

```
start /B C:\"Program Files"\SpringTools4\sts-4.5.0.RELEASE\SpringToolSuite4.exe -data %~dp0 -clean -showlocation -vmC:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -vmargs -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -vmargs -javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Here's my `SpringToolSuite4.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
-product
org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-javaagent:C:\Program Files\SpringTools4\sts-4.5.0.RELEASE\lombok.jar
```

`JAVA_HOME` environment variable is defined:

[image]

According to Eclipse documentation:

> **-vm  (Executable, Main)**
>
> when passed to the Eclipse executable, this option is used to locate the Java VM to use to run
>   Eclipse. It should be the full file system path to an appropriate:
>   Java jre/bin directory, Java Executable, Java shared library (jvm.dll
>   or libjvm.so), or a Java VM Execution Environment description file. 
>   If not specified, the Eclipse executable uses a search algorithm to
>   locate a suitable VM. In any event, the executable then passes the
>   path to the actual VM used to Java Main using the -vm argument. Java
>   Main then stores this value in eclipse.vm.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662394/missing-tools-jar-when-launching-sts-application) for possible pointers and tried different variations of configurations, i.e.:

- start STS from its .exe file and not from the above script and then specifying the workspace
- putting `-vm` option into the `.ini` file before the `-vmargs`
- pointing the `-vm` to the folder containing the `java.exe` instead of  to that specific file
- pointing to the `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe`
- having the `-vm` point to a JRE directory and not to a JDK one.
- etc.

Same error persists.

Looks like something redirects STS to look inside `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191` instead of `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin` or `C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin` where I'm pointing it to.

What could be wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

As Martin suggested, the following modification:

[image]

if invoked by double-clicking the STS executable, results in opening 2 STS windows: a regular STS one (now without the initial missing `tools.jar` prompt) plus this one:

[image]

however, when run via script from the command line, as before, fails to open STS altogether:

[image]

---

**THE FINAL SOLUTION:**

As correctly pointed out by Martin in his comment, there are several issues with the above script:

- `-vm` requires a space after it and the path to the JDK
- duplicated `-vmargs` was the culprit causing the initial erroneous behavior
- pointing to the `javaw.exe` instead of `java.exe` helps to hid the second window.
- `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` is no longer necessary under Java 8.

With the above in mind, here is what's working now:

1) The `SpringToolSuite4.ini` can stay intact, there's no need (although it's possible and working) to add the path to JDK there as pointed in my previous update:

```
  -startup
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.600.v20191014-2022.jar
    --launcher.library
    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.1100.v20190907-0426
    -product
    org.springframework.boot.ide.branding.sts4
    --launcher.defaultAction
    openFile
    -vmargs
    -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
    -Xms256m
    -Xmx1024m
    -XX:+UseG1GC
    -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
    --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
    -javaagent:C:\Program Files\SpringTools4\sts-4.5.0.RELEASE\lombok.jar
```

2) The STS can now be successfully invoked via the following (on Windows):

```
start /B C:\"Program Files"\SpringTools4\sts-4.5.0.RELEASE\SpringToolSuite4.exe -data %~dp0 -clean -showlocation -vm C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe -vmargs -Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gradle does not find tools.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345193/gradle-does-not-find-tools-jar) You should be using JDK and not JRE.

Comment: @Boris could you define `should be`?

Comment: As per the first answer following the link above - the problem is that JRE has no tools.jar and you must use JDK instead. And from the Spring Tool Suite [installation guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Installation): "All the variants require at least a JDK8+ to be installed on your system as a prerequisite".

Comment: Can you *uninstall* the JRE?

Comment: @nitind Which one? How? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `-vm` arg to the `.ini` file should work, but you need to carefully put that into the right place inside of that file. `-vm` has to be the first line in that file, followed by an additional like pointing to the java executable of the JDK. Then the third line should proceed with the `-startup` part that you have in your `.ini` file.

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  I'm seeing some improvements after incorporating your suggestion (see update in the question).  How would I modify the startup script with the `-vm` part to effect the same behavior, as I'd rather have the flexibility of that method then modifying the `.ini` file?  Or, if not, what bring about the second STS windows, I'd rather disable that?

Comment: With regards to the two windows, I think you can switch from `java.exe` to `javaw.exe` to avoid that.

Comment: with regards to the script: I never tried this myself on Windows, but I can see that there is no space between `-vm` and the actual path to the java executable and `-vmwargs` is in there twice. Maybe changing both makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, all valid pointers. The `-vmwargs` was indeed repeated and that's what was messing up the script invocation as well as the space between `-vm` and the path seems to be required. `javaw.exe` helps removing the other window. The second window also revealed this helpful warning: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0` so I removed the `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` portion in my script. I'm posting the fin solution in an update for the question so it could help someone else. Thanks!!